# Azure Service Bus Queue delete specific queued message

Tags: c#, azure, azure-servicebus-queues, service-bus-explorer

I know I can call up the scheduled message in c#/code and delete a scheduled message like this

> Scheduled messages can be removed by calling CancelScheduledMessageAsync(sequenceNumber)

But I can't seem to figure out how to do it with Service Bus Explorer or in the Azure dashboard. Is it possible with either?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to delete specific messages using QueueExplorer (I'm the author). It is a commercial tool, but if it's a one-of thing you can use free trial.

https://www.cogin.com/mq/

Btw. we are a bit lucky with scheduled messages, since Azure Service Bus API has that CancelScheduledMessageAsync function. It's more problematic for regular messages. All we can do, whether from some script or from QueueExplorer, is to start receiving all messages before the one we want deleted, and then "abandon" receive for all of those in front. It's not only slow, but increments their Delivery count and they could end up in dead letter queue. It would be great if Azure Service Bus would have "delete message" functionality in API.

Answer (score 0):

Both Azure dashboard and Service Bus Explorer do not support this option.

For Service Bus Explorer you can raise a feature request [here](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/issues).

Comment: so if I want to delete one message, I'll have to write a script to do it?

Comment: For now yes. Alternatively, use QueueExplorer just like @dejan has pointed out. And if it's something you need to perform often, nothing's wrong with supporting a tool that does it ;)